# Is this a correct way to show that a problem is coNP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, np, decision-problem, co-np

Let $A$ be a problem that I want to show it is **coNP-complete**.
I know I could just show its  complement $\bar{A}$ is NP-complete
 or that $\bar{A}$ is in NP and for some coNP-complete problem $Q$, show that $Q$ can be **Karp-reduced** to $A$.

But I wonder if the following steps are sufficient to show that **A** is **coNP-complete**?

1. Show that $A$ is in $coNP$ by showing that its complement is in NP
2. Choose one **coNP-complete** problem $Q$ and **Cook-reduce** it to $A$.

Does the coNP-complete class still be distinguishable (under the assumption $P\neq NP$) from the NP-complete class? since it seems that any coNP-complete problem is Turing-polynomially equivalent to any other NP-Complete problem.

Comment: Please make "2" more precise.  That was rather loose there.  Which type of reduction are you talking about?  Karp reduction, or Cook reduction?

Comment: 2 is a Cook reduction.

Comment: Note that at the very least you have to assume $P\not = NP$ because otherwise taking $A$ to be the empty language would falsify your statement.

Comment: I think if $P=NP$ and $A$ is the empty language then (2) will still hold since the chosen coNP-complete problem $P$ will be still solvable in poly-time; but with no call of the algorithm solving $A$. Am I missing something?

Comment: Your logic would show $A$ to be $coNP$-complete even though it isn't.

Comment: under the assumption $P=NP$, we also have $P=coNP$ and thus $NP=coNP$. so every $A \in coNP$ will be in $P$ as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the steps are insufficient. You need to use a Karp reduction, since that's the type of reduction used in the definition of coNP-completeness.

SAT is NP-complete, but probably not coNP-complete (unless NP=coNP); and coSAT is coNP-complete, but probably not NP-complete. This distinction would be lost if you used Cook reductions.

Some questions on this site which are relevant are [this one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/16386/teaching-np-completeness-turing-reductions-vs-karp-reductions) and [that one](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/84076/if-a-problem-is-cook-np-hard-and-this-problem-is-in-np-does-it-prove-that-the), as well as a few others.

Comment: Thanks! Can I with (1) and (2) conclude that $A$ is Cook-coNP-complete? considering the Cook-coNP completeness defined similarly as the coNP completeness but with the Cook reduction.

Comment: If you define a Cook-coNP-complete problem to be one that satisfies (1) and (2), then any problem that satisfies (1) and (2) is Cook-coNP-complete, by definition.

Comment: Please according to my second preoccupation when using only CooK reduction does it matter if the chosen problem to be reduced  is p-complete or coNP complete? In other words when showing that a problem $A$ is *Cook NP-hard** could I Cook  reduce a coNP-complete (such as TAUT, UNSAT) problem to $A$ instead of an NP-complete (SAT) to A?

Comment: A problem is Cook-NP-hard iff it is Cook-coNP-hard.